# Сохранение Drawable картины при повороте экрана

Tags: android

Как можно сохранить Drawable ресурс в ImageView при смене ориентации?

```
ImageView i1, i2;
Drawable p,p1,p2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_small);
    i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    i2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    p = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.picture);
    p1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.picture1);
    p2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.picture2);
    i1.setImageDrawable(p);
    i2.setImageDrawable(p);
    ... //присваиваем обработчики ImageView
}

@Override
void onClick(View v) {
    ...//проверяем на что нажали
    //при нажатии на i1
    i1.setImageDrawable(p1);
    //при нажатии на i2
    i2.setImageDrawable(p2);
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.put???("p1", ???);
    outState.put???("p2", ???);
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    i1.setImageDrawable(???);
    i2.setImageDrawable(???);
}
```

Comment: В данном коде не требуется дополнителное сохранение. Если у вас есть с этим какая то проблема - опишите ее подробнее

Comment: Извиняюсь, исправил.

Comment: Странно конечно написано. Если я правильно помню, то при вращении значения виджетов автоматически сохраняются, так что бессмысленно все это. Или я что то не так понял?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Записать int  в bundle:

```
putInt(String kye, R.drawable.*youId*);
```

затем достать его поставив в ImageView:

```
p1 = getResources().getDrawable(saveInstanceState.getInt(kye)); 
i1.setImageDrawable(p1);
```

Answer (score 0):

При повороте экрана Активити пересоздается т.е. снова вызывается метод onCreate(). А так как Вы заполняете Drawable ресурс в ImageView именно в этом методе, то он просто отработает снова. В данном случае ничего дополнительно сохранять не нужно.

Comment: Думаю, человек не просто пишет про сохранение,  не попробовав без него.

Comment: тогда нужна дополнительная информация т.к. в данном случае onCreate должен отрабатывать. Поэтому в такой реализации onSaveInstanceState нет смысла. Можно его почистить.

Comment: тогда автору следует почитать про жизнений цикл activity https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
...
     android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
...
</activity>
```